# How to mock a function to return different value based on different generic type of an argument?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a function which takes 2 arguments, a string and a TypeReference:

```
    public <T> T getConfiguration(@NonNull final String configName,
                                         @NonNull final TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
            return mapper.readValue(configString, typeReference);
    }
```

I want to make a test class for the above method and when I pass TypeReference<Map<String, List>> type, I want to return let say 'a' and if I pass TypeReference<Map<String, FeatureLaunchStatus>> I want 'b' to be returned:

```
        Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(Mockito.eq(SDK_BYTES), Mockito.<TypeReference<Map<String, List<String>>>>any()))
                .thenReturn(a);
        Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(Mockito.eq(SDK_BYTES), Mockito.<TypeReference<Map<String, FeatureLaunchStatus>>>any()))
                .thenReturn(b);
```

But, I am getting 'b' in both cases. How to get 'a' for TypeReference<Map<String, List>> type and 'b' for TypeReference<Map<String, FeatureLaunchStatus>> type?

I also tried ArgumentMatchers instead of Mockito, but it also is giving 'b' in both case.

Or please tell any other way how to mock, I have to call once of type         TypeReference<Map<String, List>> and once of              TypeReference<Map<String, FeatureLaunchStatus>> and need different values to be returned.

Comment: have you tried removing the any() argument and put a concrete object in your 2nd argument?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `thenAnswer` for more flexibility. This will give you the `invocations` object, containing the parameters of the call. This is a simplified example:

```
class MyMapper {
    public <T> T getConfiguration(String configName, TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Test
void test() {
    MyMapper mocked = mock(MyMapper.class);
    when(mocked.getConfiguration(any(), any()))
            .thenAnswer(invocation -> {
                TypeReference<?> typeReference = invocation.getArgument(1);
                // maybe you'll find a more elegant way to do this check
                if (typeReference.getType().getTypeName().equals("java.util.List<java.lang.String>")) {
                    return List.of("a");
                }
                return Map.of("aa", "bb");
            });


    TypeReference<List<String>> listTr = new TypeReference<List<String>>() {};
    List<String> result = mocked.getConfiguration("lala", listTr);
    System.out.println(result); //prints ['a']

    TypeReference<Map<String, String>> mapTr = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {};
    Map<String, String> result2 = mocked.getConfiguration("lala", mapTr);
    System.out.println(result2); //prints {'aa':'bb'}
}
```

On the other hand - when it gets to such complicated Mokito setup, you might consider writing your own fake object or use the actual object if possible. Hope this helps.